# Why the camera is not moving at all if the rotation speed value is for example set to 0.01?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If I set the rotation speed to 5 for example it will rotate facing the next target waypoint and then will move to it. But the camera rotation will be too fast.

Changing the speed to 0.01 make it rotating in a good slowly smooth speed. But then at 0.01 the camera rotate facing the next waypoint but never move to it. It stay on place.

This is the waypoints script:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Waypoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject[] waypoints;
    private Transform currentWaypoint;

    private enum CameraState
    {
        StartRotating,
        Rotating,
        Moving,
        Waiting
    }

    private CameraState cameraState;

    public GameObject player;
    public float speed = 5;
    public float WPradius = 1;
    public LookAtCamera lookAtCam;

    void Start()
    {
        cameraState = CameraState.StartRotating;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        switch (cameraState)
        {
            // This state is used as a trigger to set the camera target and start rotation
            case CameraState.StartRotating:
                {
                    // Sanity check in case the waypoint array was set to length == 0 between states
                    if (waypoints.Length == 0)
                        break;

                    // Tell the camera to start rotating
                    currentWaypoint = waypoints[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, waypoints.Length)].transform;
                    lookAtCam.target = currentWaypoint;
                    lookAtCam.setTime(0.0f);
                    cameraState = CameraState.Rotating;

                    break;
                }

            // This state only needs to detect when the camera has completed rotation to start movement
            case CameraState.Rotating:
                {
                    if (lookAtCam.IsRotationFinished)
                        cameraState = CameraState.Moving;

                    break;
                }

            case CameraState.Moving:
                {
                    // Move
                    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, currentWaypoint.position, Time.deltaTime * speed);

                    // Check for the Waiting state
                    if (Vector3.Distance(currentWaypoint.position, transform.position) < WPradius)
                    {
                        // Set to waiting state
                        cameraState = CameraState.Waiting;

                        // Call the coroutine to wait once and not in CameraState.Waiting
                        // Coroutine will set the next state
                        StartCoroutine(WaitForTimer(3));
                    }

                    break;
                }
            case CameraState.Waiting:
                // Do nothing. Timer has already started
                break;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator WaitForTimer(float timer)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timer);
        cameraState = CameraState.StartRotating;
    }

    public void RefreshWaypoints()
    {
        waypoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Target");
    }
}
```

And the look at camera script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LookAtCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Values that will be set in the Inspector
    public Transform target;
    public float RotationSpeed;

    private float timer = 0.0f;
    public bool IsRotationFinished
    {
        get { return timer > 0.99f; }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (target != null && timer < 0.99f)
        {
            // Rotate us over time according to speed until we are in the required rotation
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation,
                Quaternion.LookRotation((target.position - transform.position).normalized),
                timer);

            timer += Time.deltaTime * RotationSpeed;
        }
    }

    public void setTime(float time)
    {
        timer = time;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Problem

Your script basically works! The problem is in

```
private void Update()
{
    if (target != null && timer < 0.99f)
    {
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation((target.position - transform.position).normalized), timer);

        timer += Time.deltaTime * RotationSpeed;
    }
}
```

there are two issues with that:

1. You add `Time.deltaTime * RotationSpeed` so the time it takes to reach the `1` or in your case `0.99` simply takes `1/RotationSpeed = 100` times longer than usual. So your camera will stay in the `Rotating` state for about **100 seconds** - after that it moves just fine!
2. (This one might be intentional but see below for a **Better Solution**) `Quaternion.Slerp` interpolates between the first and second rotation. But you always use the current rotation as startpoint so since the `timer` never reaches `1` you get a very fast rotation at the beginning but a very slow (in fact never ending) rotation in the end since the distance between the current rotation and the target rotation gets smaller over time.

---

## Quick-Fixes

Those fixes repair your current solution but you should checkout the section **Better Solution** below ;)

1. In general for comparing both `float` values you should rather use [Mathf.Approximately](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html) and than use the actual target value `1`.

   ```
   if (target != null && !Mathf.Approximately(timer, 1.0f))
   {
       //...

       timer += Time.deltaTime * RotationSpeed;

       // clamps the value between 0 and 1
       timer = Mathf.Clamp01(timer);
   }
   ```

   and

   ```
   public bool IsRotationFinished
   {
       get { return Mathf.Approximately(timer, 1.0f); }
   }
   ```
2. You should either use `Quaternion.Slerp` storing the original rotation and use it as first parameter (than you will see that you need a way bigger `RotationSpeed`)

   ```
   private Quaternion lastRotation;

   private void Update()
   {
       if (target != null && !Mathf.Approximately(timer, 1.0f))
       {
           transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(lastRotation, Quaternion.LookRotation((target.position - transform.position).normalized), timer);

           timer += Time.deltaTime * RotationSpeed;
       }
       else
       {
           lastRotation = transform.rotation;
       }
   }
   ```

   Or instead of `Quaternion.Slerp` use [`Quaternion.RotateTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html) like

   ```
   transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, Quaternion.LookRotation((target.position - transform.position).normalized), RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
   ```

---

## Better Solution

I would strongly suggest to use the [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) for everything instead of handling this kind of stuff in `Update`. They are way easier to control and makes your code very clean.

Look how your scripts would shrink and you wouldn't need all the properties, fields and comparing `floats` anymore. You could do most things you are currently getting and setting to wait for a certain thing to happen in only a few single lines.

In case you didn't know: You can actually simply `yield return` another `IEnumerator` on order to wait for it to finish:

### Waypoints

```
public class Waypoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject[] waypoints;

    public GameObject player;
    public float speed = 5;
    public float WPradius = 1;
    public LookAtCamera lookAtCam;

    private Transform currentWaypoint;    

    private void Start()
    {
        // maybe refresh here?
        //RefreshWaypoints();
        StartCoroutine(RunWaypoints());
    }

    private IEnumerator RunWaypoints()
    {
        // Sanity check in case the waypoint array has length == 0
        if (waypoints.Length == 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("No Waypoints!", this);
            yield break;
        }

        // this looks dnagerous but as long as you yield somewhere it's fine ;)
        while (true)
        {
            // maybe refresh here?
            //RefreshWaypoints();

            // Sanity check in case the waypoint array was set to length == 0 between states
            if (waypoints.Length == 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("No Waypoints!", this);
                yield break;
            }

            // first select the next waypoint
            // Note that you might get the exact same waypoint again you currently had
            // this will throw two errors in Unity:
            // - Look rotation viewing vector is zero
            // - and transform.position assign attempt for 'Main Camera' is not valid. Input position is { NaN, NaN, NaN }.
            //
            // so to avoid that rather use this (not optimal) while loop
            // ofcourse while is never good but the odds that you will
            // always get the same value over a longer time are quite low
            //
            // in case of doubt you could still add a yield return null
            // than your camera just waits some frames longer until it gets a new waypoint
            Transform newWaypoint = waypoints[Random.Range(0, waypoints.Length)].transform;
            while(newWaypoint == currentWaypoint)
            {
                newWaypoint = waypoints[Random.Range(0, waypoints.Length)].transform;
            }
            currentWaypoint = newWaypoint;

            // tell camera to rotate and wait until it is finished in one line!
            yield return lookAtCam.RotateToTarget(currentWaypoint);

            // move and wait until in correct position in one line!
            yield return MoveToTarget(currentWaypoint);

            //once waypoint reached wait 3 seconds than start over
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator MoveToTarget(Transform currentWaypoint)
    {
        var currentPosition = transform.position;
        var duration = Vector3.Distance(currentWaypoint.position, transform.position) / speed;
        var passedTime = 0.0f; 

        do
        {
            // for easing see last section below
            var lerpFactor = passedTime / duration;

            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(currentPosition, currentWaypoint.position, lerpFactor);

            passedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        } while (passedTime <= duration);

        // to be sure to have the exact position in the end set it fixed
        transform.position = currentWaypoint.position;
    }

    public void RefreshWaypoints()
    {
        waypoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Target");
    }
}
```

### LookAtCamera

```
public class LookAtCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Values that will be set in the Inspector
    public float RotationSpeed;

    public IEnumerator RotateToTarget(Transform target)
    {
        var timePassed = 0f;

        var targetDirection = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;

        var targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetDirection);
        var currentRotation = transform.rotation;

        var duration = Vector3.Angle(targetDirection, transform.forward) / RotationSpeed;  

        do
        {
            // for easing see last section below
            var lerpFactor = timePassed / duration; 

            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(currentRotation, targetRotation, lerpFactor);

            timePassed += Time.deltaTime;

            yield return null;
        } while (timePassed <= duration);

        // to be sure you have the corrcet rotation in the end set it fixed
        transform.rotation = targetRotation;
    }
}
```

[image]

#### Note

Again instead of `Quaternion.Slerp` and `currentRotation` you could also simply use [`Quaternion.RotateTowards`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html) like

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation, RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

And for the movement you can also still use `Vector3.MoveTowards` if you want

```
while (Vector3.Distance(currentWaypoint.position, transform.position) < WPradius)
{
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, currentWaypoint.position, Time.deltaTime * speed);
    yield return null;
}
```

**but** I would prefer to use the `Lerp` solutions. Why I suggest to rather use `Lerp`?

1. You can very easy controll now whether you want to move/rotate by a certain speed or rather give it fixed `duration` in which the move/rotation shall be finished regardless how big the differenc is - or even have some additional checks in order to decide for one of those options!
2. You can ease-in and -out the movement/rotation! See below ;)

---

## Hint for easing Lerp movements

For still maintaining an eased-in and/or eased-out movement and rotation I found this block [How to Lerp like a pro](https://chicounity3d.wordpress.com/2014/05/23/how-to-lerp-like-a-pro/) very helpfull! (adopted to my examples)

> For example, we could “ease out” with sinerp:
>
> ```
> var lerpFactor = Mathf.Sin(passedTime / duration * Mathf.PI * 0.5f);
> ```
>
> Or we could “ease in” with coserp:
>
> ```
> var lerpFactor = 1f - Mathf.Cos(passedTime / duration * Mathf.PI * 0.5f);
> ```
>
> We could even create exponential movement:
>
> ```
> var lerpFactor = Mathf.Pow(passedTime / duration, 2);
> ```
>
> The multiplication property mentioned above is the core concept behind some interpolation methods which ease in and ease out, such as the famous “smoothstep” formula:
>
> ```
> var lerpFactor = Mathf.Pow(passedTime / duration, 2) * (3f - 2f * passedTime / duration);
> ```
>
> Or my personal favorite, “smootherstep”:
>
> ```
> var lerpFactor = Mathf.Pow(passedTime / duration, 3) * (6f * (passedTime / duration) - 15f) + 10f);
> ```

Comment: Working great. One small question. If I want that the camera will stop a bit before the waypoint/s ? Before I used the variable WPradius as for stop distance and set it to 15 but now it's not in use.

Comment: And another thing I noticed now. If I generate the waypoints just generate cubes randomly positions but also in a random height between 0 and 100 for some reason now the camera is shaking/stuttering when moving and rotating. Until now all the cubes the waypoints was at the same height 10.

Comment: If you spawn to many waypoints it might just happen that the difference between them gets to small so the camera almost allways already looks into the correct direction/is already almost in the correct position. In order to keep the radius just calculate it to your targetPosition: `var targetPosition = currentWayPoint.position - (currentWayPoint.position - transform.position). normalized * WPRadius;`

Comment: The camera problem is fine now solved. The radius distance is not working. Inside the method IEnumerator MoveToTarget I added the line var targetPosition = currentWayPoint.position - (currentWayPoint.position - transform.position). normalized * WPRadius; and then on the distance calculation line I did: var duration = Vector3.Distance(targetPosition, transform.position) / speed; But it didn't change much and WPRadius is set to 15.